# parsing large xml 500M with node.js

Tags: xml, node.js, sax

I am using [isaacs' SAX](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js) to parse a huge xml file. Also [recommended by La Gentz](http://blog.lagentz.com/nodejs/nodejs-parsing-and-transforming-large-xml-documents/).

The process uses about 650M of memory, how can I reduce this or allow node to use even more.

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

My XML file is larger than 300M it could grow to 1GB.

Comment: Sounds like you need to allow for more memory usage in your php.ini file. Look for `memory_limit` in your .ini file and change the value to allow for the largest file you expect to handle.

Comment: Are you trying to save the XML file as a JSON file? Or do you need the entire to keep the entire Javascript object in memory?

Comment: I am using node.js - I could not locate a parameter to raise memory limit. (man node, lot's of options)

Comment: @DeaDEnD I don't neet the entire tree. Getting the error while parsing: `parser.write(file_buf.toString('utf8'), lenght).close();`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should stream the file into the parser, that's the whole point of a streaming parser after all.

```
var parser = require('sax').createStream(strict, options);
fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(parser);
```

Comment: This is the way to do it if you don't want/need the whole document in memory. Node is actually not a great solution because it is single-threaded. So, while parsing this enormous document, the process won't be able to do anything else, such as response to HTTP requests.

Comment: @danmactough, what would you recommend to use? For now this solution is great and works for me. I go through that document and let my worker do the one time job, which is not critical.

Comment: @DeaDEnD, thanks. Do you or others know how to emit a end signal on that parser, so parser stops and parser.onend would be called, while parsing?

Comment: You could try calling `readstream.destroy()` to stop the stream from reading the file and `parser.end()` to signal the parser that the stream has ended.

Comment: @vik If you don't care about the blocking, then node is fine. You'll get better performance out of one of the c++ based parsers -- sax.js, while awesome, is pure javascript. Not sure if other xml parsers provide a Stream interface though.

Comment: @DeaDEnD I had tried parser.end, but getting an error. What I am now doing is `if (index > max) { parser.emit('end'); return }` which stops after a few more iterations. Thank your for your help.

Comment: @danmactough, I thought you would come up with c++, but that is out of question :). Team and me are not so good with c++. If it get's critical I'll consider c++ or other languages.

Comment: @vik What I meant was continue using node, but instead of sax.js, use libxmljs or another c++ parser. They all allow you to continue coding in javascript without knowing a lick about c++. :)

Comment: @vik & @DeaDEnd You may want to look at `.destroySoon()`. http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/streams.html#stream.destroySoon

Comment: Forgive the shameless plug... I have built a simpler parser on top of sax that makes things super easy: https://github.com/matthewmatician/xml-flow.