# MongoDB + nodejs. Reading 2 million xml files and store there data into mongoDB

Tags: xml, node.js, mongodb

I want import around 2 million xml files to MongoDB.

I built a little program which opens all the file, grabs the data i need out of the xml files, structures the data and saves it to a MongoDB database.

This process should cause around 6 million objects in MongoDB. every object consists out of four stings with maximum 50 characters.

The problem is, that it is super slow.

On my test maschine (window 7) windows has problems opening folder with many files. I'm not sure if that influences node and MongoDB.

Maybe the code i wrote isn't that fast.

Maybe MongoDB isn't made for this kind of task.

I want to send back the data via Json, thus my client application can use it.

Maybe you can tell me if I'm on the right path with my project...

```
require('../models/Keyword');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//ggf. ohne Variable zuzuweisen
var Keyword = mongoose.model("Keyword");

function start() {
    var fs = require('fs');
    //XML
    var jsxml = require("node-jsxml");
    var Namespace = jsxml.Namespace,
        QName = jsxml.QName,
        XML = jsxml.XML,
        XMLList = jsxml.XMLList;

    var EventEmitter=require('events').EventEmitter;
    var dateinamenEE=new EventEmitter();
    var dateinamen = [];

    var laenge;
    var pieces;
    var basiswort;
    var neuesKeyword;
    var buf; 
    var xml;
    var list;
    var temp;
    var ergebnis;
    var buchstabe;
    var obj;

    fs.readdir('./data/data10/data/', function (err, files) { 
        if (!err) {
            files.forEach(function(value) {
                dateinamen.push(value);
            });
            dateinamenEE.emit('dateinamen_ready');
        } else {
            throw err; 
        }
    });

    dateinamenEE.on('dateinamen_ready',function(){
        dateinamen.forEach(function(value) {
                try {
                    buf = fs.readFileSync('./data/data10/data/'+value, "utf8");
                    xml = new XML(buf);
                    list = xml.descendants("suggestion");
                    temp = "";
                    ergebnis = "";
                    buchstabe = "";
                    obj = null; 
                    list.each(function(item, index){
                        ergebnis = item.attribute('data').toString()
                        temp = decodeURIComponent(value);
                        temp = temp.replace(".xml", "");
                        pieces = temp.split("+");
                        basiswort = "";
                        laenge = pieces.length-1
                        buchstabe = pieces[laenge]
                        for(var i = 0; i < laenge; i++) {
                            basiswort = basiswort +" "+ pieces[i];
                        } 
                        basiswort = basiswort.replace (/^\s+/, '').replace (/\s+$/, '');
                        uniqueKey = basiswort+buchstabe+ergebnis;
                        uniqueKey = uniqueKey.replace(/\s/g, "");

                        obj = {_id: uniqueKey, basis: basiswort, buchstabe: buchstabe, ergebnis: ergebnis};
                        neuesKeyword = new Keyword(obj);
                        neuesKeyword.save();
                    });
                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.log(e.stack);
                }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I think it would help to use batch based saving of the documents. But the bottleneck is probably the DOM parsing of each document. I recommend some profiling before optimizing to find the bottleneck.

Comment: Ok the Import now shows an error FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak. I do not know how this code exactly works in terms of synchronisation. I mean is it possible that to much things run in parallel? You should print a few variables (or add counters) out to understand the flow in which things are happening here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parsing large xml 500M with node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707255/parsing-large-xml-500m-with-node-js)